# `$_` variable giving incorrect output

Tags: perl

If I do

```
my @answer = qw(java python perl c);
foreach (@answer){
          print "[$_]\n";
}
```

then it will print

```
[java]
[python]
[perl]
[c]
```

But, if I add `$answer` before `[$_]`:

```
my @answer = qw(java python perl c);
foreach (@answer){
       print "$answer[$_]\n";
}
```

then it will print

```
java java java java
```

*Why is that?*

Comment: [Always `use strict` and always `use warnings`](http://joelslinux.blogspot.com/2011/06/use-strict-and-warnings.html)

Answer (score 13):

Each element in the loop is put into `$_`. When you say `$answer[$_]`, you're asking for the array element `$answer['java']`, `$answer['python']`, and so on. These strings turn into `0` in numeric context, and therefore what you get is `$answer[0]`, which is `java`.

Comment: sucks when they don’t use warnings, doesn’t it?

Answer (score 6):

Your first loop:

```
foreach (@answer){
    print "[$_]\n";
}
```

Iterates over `@answer` and puts the current element of the `@answer` array in `$_` on each pass through the loop. The result is that you get the elements of `@answer` printed in order.

Your second loop:

```
foreach (@answer) {
    print "$answer[$_]\n";
}
```

Does the same iteration with the same values in `$_`. But, and this is a big but, you're printing `$answer[$_]` and `$_` is a string each time and that string is zero in a numeric context so you're effectively doing this:

```
print "$answer[0]\n";
```

four times in a row. Hence your four `java` strings. And your second chunk of sample output left out the newlines between the `java` strings.

Comment: Huh? This is a warnings bug, not a strict bug.

Comment: @tchrist: True enough, my fingers have been programmed to `use strict;use warnings;` for so long that I've forgotten which warnings come from which things.

Comment: strict never warns; it dies. Maybe you use FATAL warnings?

Answer (score 0):

$_ is actually the string at the current index of the loop. It's equivalent to this in Java:

```
String[] x = new String[]{ "java", "perl"...};
for (String y : x) {
...
}
```

$_ would be equivalent to `y`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@answer); $i++)
{
    print "$answer[$i]\n";
}
```

or print `$answer[0]` to get first element of the array

Comment: If you want a counter, then `for my $i ( 0 .. $#answer )` is a better idiom.

Comment: Or, if you have a sufficiently new Perl (5.12 or better), `while (my($i, $a) = each @answer)`.